# How to revert a commit in this scenario?

Tags: git, github

Ok, so I'm trying to install a piece of software (gnuradio) on my Fedora 29 machine. To get it to work, I'm told I have to "Revert this patch https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/pull/2756".

But I don't exactly know how to do that... I tried just "git revert"+that link, but that wasn't right. I also tried "git revert"+the commit hash, no dice.

Further, I tried those two things with "git cherry-pick" and "git apply -R," all of which failed.

Clearly I'm a bit less experienced with git than I thought; how would I go about reverting this patch?

Thanks!

Comment: `git checkout 4fdba092`?

Comment: I figured there's some way to revert the changes made by a specific commit/patch without reverting everything downstream of it. But yeah, I suppose checking out the commit right before the patch is worth a shot.

Comment: read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head-undo-commits/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 0):

Looking at PR [2756](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/pull/2756) it ended up as commit [2a76171](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/commit/2a76171f40f4b427160cd5fbc2feac96e27404d7?diff=unified) on `master`.

This would mean you should do `git revert 2a76171`.